# What phrase could be used in place of "threw out their nets" or "threw their nets"?

Tags: vocabulary

> The fishermen **threw out/threw their** nets.

For fishing, which phrase should be used, "threw out their nets" or "threw their nets"?

Answer (score 1):

You could say

The fishermen [cast](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20fishermen%20*%20their%20nets&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthe%20fishermen%20%2A%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20cast%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20spread%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20mending%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20drawing%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20with%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20draw%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20of%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20in%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20casting%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20fishermen%20drying%20their%20nets%3B%2Cc0) their nets.

Comment: Thanks, TRomano. I'd like to know whether it is possible to use threw out or threw.

Comment: Both **threw their nets** and **threw their nets out** are grammatical and would be acceptable, although they are not used as often with fishing nets as **cast** is.  The meaning of **throw** is broader.  Note that **threw out** has the additional meaning of "put into the trash can, discarded".

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of definitions for [throw out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/throw%20out) but casting a net is definitely not one of them.

To me *throw out* sounds like *throw away sth when you no longer need it*. You can *throw out your net* ofcourse when it no longer can be used or is too old so you put it in a trash can.

You can *throw* or *cast* a net to catch some fish. The net is cast or thrown by hand in such a manner that it spreads out on the water and sinks. This technique is called **net casting** or **net throwing**.